# how to get system environment variable in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

My rails application is running in 3 servers namely [testing.example.com, staging.example.com, example.com] Whenever sending email, I have set host option with 'liverserver_url' for default_url_options in production.rb. I need to get system environment variable to set host option dynamically. how to do that. How to get system environment variable in rails application.

Answer (score 1):

```
export MAIL_HOST='your_url'
```

Add below line to `/etc/environment` file

```
MAIL_HOST='your_url' and restart the machine.
```

you can access `ENV['MAIL_HOST']` in rails application anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can get environment from next variables
`ENV["RAILS_ENV"]`
`ENV["RAKE_ENV"]`
`Rails.env`

But you have to configure your server for using `production.rb` `staging.rb` and another environment file in your config directory and then configure specific environment.

Comment: I should run in production mode in 3 servers. I will set system environment variable in each server like export MAIL_HOST='testing.example.com', export MAIL_HOST='staging.example.com', export MAIL_HOST='example.com' in each server respectively. So, how do I get this environment variable in my rails application, so that I can set this variable for default_url_options which will fetch dynamically.

Comment: @thrillsam in ruby code you can use ENV['MAIL_HOST']

Comment: I fixed it by below steps.

export MAIL_HOST='example.com'  in console

Added below line in /etc/environment and restart the machine
MAIL_HOST='example.com'

I can get ENV['MAIL_HOST'] in rails application